# How to display progress of the TFDScript execution using TProgressBar?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

I have some script in some file "MyScript.sql"
On the form I have my TProgressBar.
I want to read script with TFDScript and move progressbar according to the script.

My code is

```
    Var

      Lista: TStringList; // SQL DDL list for creating table and populate table
      I: Integer;
    Begin

  With FDConn Do    //FDConn is my FaireDac connection
  Begin
    LoginPrompt := False;
    With Params Do
    Begin
      Clear;
      DriverID := 'SQLite';
      Database := 'MyDatabase.sdb';
      LoginPrompt := False;
    End;

    Lista := TStringList.Create;
    Lista.Clear;
    Try

      FDScript.ValidateAll;   //FDScript is TFDScript and prgBar is TProgressBar
      prgBar.Max := FDScript.TotalJobSize - 1;
      prgBar.Update;

      Lista.Clear;
      Lista.LoadFromFile('MyScript.sql');

// Now how I can read script 1 line by 1 line and move progress bar with
prgBar.StepIt;
prgBar.Update;`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the [**OnProgress**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Script.TFDScript.OnProgress) event and read there e.g. [**TotalJobSize**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Script.TFDScript.TotalJobSize) property to determine the number of bytes to proceed and [**TotalJobDone**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Script.TFDScript.TotalJobDone) to get number of bytes processed. For example:

```
procedure TForm1.FDScript1Progress(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProgressBar1.Max := TFDScript(Sender).TotalJobSize;
  ProgressBar1.Position := TFDScript(Sender).TotalJobDone;
end;
```

If you were having progress bar control with progress value setup by percentage, you'd better read the [**TotalPct10Done**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Script.TFDScript.TotalPct10Done) property.

Comment: I don't know how, can you post some code how that work?

Comment: Sure :) I've added an example. Not for `TotalPct10Done` though. For `TProgressBar` is better to read `TotalJobSize` and `TotalJobDone`.